# how to run subdomain through controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and i want to run sub domain from one specific controller. i changed my route.php file under config folder like this

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {

case 'property.mywebsite.com':
    $route['default_controller'] = "students";
break;

case 'admin.mywebsite.com':
    $route['default_controller'] = "teachers";
default:
    $route['default_controller'] = "home";
    // The list of your $routes lines at is was...
break;
}
```

When i used it show this error

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

should i have to change my htaccess file also?
please help me.

Comment: Does "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']" returning subdomin value ?

Comment: post your folder structure...